# Espérance vs espoir?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I see that both of these seem to translate to the noun *hope*. What is the difference between them, if any? It seems that one gives *espérance* but has *espoir*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Espoir seems to be more focused, and more tangible. Espérance refers more to a state of mind, more like optimism. Espoir is widely used in French, as opposed to espérance which is a not-so-used word.

ex. J'espère (j'ai l'espoir) que le repas sera bon (I hope the meal will be good). vs Il est plein d'espérance (he is full of hope)

Comment: I would add that espérance applies in religious or spiritual contexts.

Answer (score 1):

while "espoir" (https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/espoir) -which is the  "Déverbal" of "espérer"- is a neutral,**abstract**,down-to-earth and everyday life word,"espérance"(https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/esp%C3%A9rance) is formal and **more focused on the action** by itself...

In deed,"espérance" can be split into the stem that comes from "espérer" plus the sufix "**-ance**" which gives all the nuance to that word :the sufix "-ance" indicates an action or the result of an action (https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ance).
"espérance" is widely used in theological literacy and mathematics :

> l'espérance mathématique d'une variable aléatoire réelle est, intuitivement, la valeur que l'on s'attend à trouver, en moyenne, si l'on répète un grand nombre de fois la même expérience aléatoire

(https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esp%C3%A9rance_math%C3%A9matique)

Finally,i dare say that "espérance"" is for situations in which we are **sure about the result** while "espoir" has a nuance of **great uncertainty**.

Answer (score 1):

Espoir est horizontal, espérance est vertical. Espoir is horizontal (concrete, grounded, material...), while espérance is vertical (spiritual, inspirational, greater...)

Answer (score 0):

Correct usage is *L'espérance de vie* and not *L'espoir de vie* that could help clarify usage for both. That's how I came to this anyway, always thought the correct term was "espoir de vie"

Comment: *L'espérance de vie* (futur) est d'environ quatre-vingt ans, avec *l'espoir d'une vie* (matérielle) meilleure grâce aux progrès de la médecine