# Difference between Désespoir and désespérance

Tags: sens

Both désespoir and désespérance exist in French, they seem to be synonymous. But what is the difference between those two words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is essentially the same than between [*espoir* and *espérance*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11450/esp%C3%A9rance-vs-espoir).

*Désespoir* is common and can be used in all cases while *désespérance* is rare and cannot always replace *désespoir*.

See also http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/archive/2009/05/10/o-rage-o-desesperance.html

Answer (score 2):

*Désespérance* is rarely used.

- TLF understands that it **seems** more pessimistic than *désespoir*.
- If, for Batchelor (in Using French Synonyms) *désespoir* = *despair*, *désespérance* = *despair + lack of faith*

Answer (score 2):

*Désespérance* to me has religious overtones being the contrary of *espérance*, one of the three theologal virtues with *foi* (faith) and *charité* (charity). Thus *désespérance* is the state that Christians find themselves in when they have lost hope in God.

Apart from this specialized meaning, it means much the same thing as *désespoir*, with the following nuance however that can be inferred from Walther von Wartburg's remark about *désespérance* in his Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch :

- *Désespérance*, ungebräuchlich im 17. und 18. jh., wurde von der *Ecole romantique* und den *Symbolistes* wieder aufgegriffen, ist heute aber vor allem literarisch und wirkt abstrakter und negativer als *deséspoir*.

My translation :

- *Désespérance*, rarely used in the 17th and 18th centuries, was revived by the *Ecole romantique* and the *Symbolistes*, it is now mostly literary and comes across as more abstract and negative than *désespoir*.